# What the different between MySQL Native Driver and MySQL Client Library

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqlnd

I want to know the different between MySQL Native Driver and MySQL Client Library and when to use both of them

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php

Comment: @robert: MySQLnd (and the MySQL client library) are PHP extensions (drivers) that *provide* the `mysqli` functions.  That code will work with either one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no big difference in the PHP language level.

- libmysqlclient distributed by MySQL, mysqlnd distributed by PHP.
- libmysqlclient is part of MySQL, you need install MySQL library.
- Their license are different.
- mysqlnd supports a lot of plugins (mysqlnd_ms & mysqlnd_qc & ...).
- Because mysqlnd is part of PHP, its memory could be limited by PHP configuration.
- mysqlnd is the default after 5.4

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php

Answer (score 7):

**mysql**:

- dual licence
- optional automatic reconnect
- all memory allocation and deallocation is done using operating system memory management

**mysqlnd**:

- PHP licence
- Non-blocking, asynchronous queries
- [Performance statistics](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.stats.php) ([mysqli_get_client_stats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-get-client-stats.php), [mysqli_get_connection_stats](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-connection-stats.php))
- LOAD LOCAL INFILE respects the open_basedir directive
- All memory allocation and deallocation is done using the PHP memory management functions (you can track memory usage with [PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) and [debug features](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.config.php#ini.mysqlnd.debug), and also PHP memory limits apply which has its pros and cons)

**mysqlnd** via plugins:

- [Replication and load balancing](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-ms.php)
- Fail over
- Lazy connections
- [Connection multiplexing](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-mux.php)
- [Query caching](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd-qc.php), [MySQL InnoDB Memcached Plugin support](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd-memcache.php)
- Transparent query manipulations (auto-EXPLAIN)

**incompatibilities** between mysql and mysqlnd:

- values of bit data type are returned as binary strings with mysql.so and as decimal strings with mysqlnd.so ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.incompatibilities.php)).

Based on this and other docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php