# class "mysqli" on php version 8.0 , deprecated?

Tags: php, mysqli, cpanel

Was the "mysqli" class deprecated for version 8.0 of php?

My DB connection script stopped working after I upgraded cPanel to version 8.0 .

error: "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found"

**With Version php 7.4:**

[image: Version 7.4]

**With Version php 8.0:**

[image]

Comment: `nd_mysqli`, right below what you marked with the red rectangle, should work. (The differences between native driver and client library can be neglected in most cases, https://stackoverflow.com/q/21534468/1427878)

Comment: @CBroe, resolved by activating the `nd_mysqli` extension as you suggested. Will I have any inconvenience related to performance or security, what do you advise me to do? Extension `mysqli` on v7.4 and the `nd_mysqli` on v8.0 are the same thing? TY

Comment: No, they are not the same thing. I linked to a thread that explains the main differences.

Comment: It looks like cpanel finally removed support for libmysqlclient